# Kernel of characteristic polynomial of linear transformation

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, characteristic-polynomial

Let $F$ be a Field and $V$ be a Vectorspace with $\dim(V)=n$. Let $f:V \to V$ be a linear transformation with the characteristic polynomial $pa(x)$.
It is linear factorized. Let $pa(x)=g(x)*h(x)$ with the greatest common divisier  $\gcd(g,h)=1$.

> a) $V_g=ker(g(f))$ and $V_h=ker(h(f))$. Show $V_g \cap V_h=\{0\}$.
>
> b) Show $\dim(V_g)+\dim(V_h)=n$.
>
> c) $V=V_g+V_h$

Comment: Terry Tao wrote a great blog article were he answers a question almost exactly like this. Here's a link: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/10/12/the-jordan-normal-form-and-the-euclidean-algorithm/

Comment: Here's a hint: if $p(x)$ is any polynomial satisfying $p(f)=0$, and $p(x)=g(x)\cdot h(x)$ for some relatively prime polynomials $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, then you can prove claims **(a)** and **(c)** from the fact that there exist polynomials $a(x)$, $b(x)$ with $a(x)\cdot g(x)+b(x)\cdot h(x)=1$. Claim **(b)** follows from claims **(a)** and **(c)**.

Comment: I've made a few revisions to the answer I posted. If anything I wrote is unclear, let me know. I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll prove **(a)** and **(c)** using Bezout's identity. **(b)** follows from **(a)** and **(c)**. Also, I'm going to use slightly different notation. If $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation and $x\in V$, then I'm going to write $Tx$ instead of writing $T(x)$.

Let $F$ be a field, let $V$ be an $F$-vector space with $\dim(V)=n$, and let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Let $p(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $T$. We're given that $p(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $GCD(g,h)=1$. Let $V_g=\ker(g(T))$ and let $V_h=\ker(h(T))$. We want to show the following:

**(a)** $V_g\cap V_h=\{0\}$.

**(b)** $\dim(V_g)+\dim(V_h)=n$

**(c)** $V_g+V_h=V$.

Note: it follows from Bezout's identity that there exist polynomials $a(x)$, $b(x)$ with

$$a(x)g(x)+b(x)h(x)=1.$$

Also note that the Cayley-Hamilton theorem says that $p(T)=0$.

**(a)** Let $x\in V_g\cap V_h$. Our goal is to show $x=0$. Since

$$a(x)g(x)+b(x)h(x)=1,$$

it follows that

$$a(T)g(T)+b(T)h(T)=I,$$

where $I:V\to V$ is the identity transformation. Hence

$$x=Ix=\left[a(T)g(T)+b(T)h(T)\right]x=a(T)g(T)x+b(T)h(T)x=a(T)0+b(T)0=0.$$

Hence $x=0$.

**(c)** Let $x\in V$. Our goal is to show that $x=y+z$ for some $y\in V_g$, $z\in V_h$. Since

$$g(x)a(x)+h(x)b(x)=1,$$

it follows that

$$g(T)a(T)+h(T)b(T)=I.$$

Hence

$$x=Ix=\left[g(T)a(T)+h(T)b(T)\right]x=g(T)a(T)x+h(T)b(T)x.$$

Let $y=b(T)x$ and $z=a(T)x$. Then $x=y+z$. Also $y\in V_g$ since

$$g(T)y=g(T)h(T)b(T)x=p(T)b(T)x$$

and $p(T)b(T)x=0$, because $P(T)=0$.

Similarly, $z\in V_h$ since

$$h(T)z=h(T)g(T)a(T)x=p(T)a(T)x$$

and $p(T)a(T)x=0$, because $P(T)=0$.

**(b)** For any vector space $W$ with subspace $W_1$, $W_2$, we have that

$$\dim(W_1+W_2)+\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=\dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2).$$

It follows that

$$
\begin{align*}
\dim(V_g)+\dim(V_h) &=\dim(V_g+V_h)+\dim(V_g\cap V_h) \\
&=\dim(V)+\dim(\{0\}) \\
&=n+0 \\
&=n.
\end{align*}
$$

**Final Comment:** Note that to prove **(a)** we only needed that $GCD(h,g)=1$, and to prove **(c)** we only needed that $GCD(g,h)=1$ and that $g(x)h(x)=p(x)$ for some polynomial $p(x)$ with $p(T)=0$. So claims **(a)**, **(b)**, **(c)** would hold whenever we have a polynomial $p(x)$ with $p(T)=0$ and $p(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with for some $g$, $h$ with $GCD(g,h)=1$.